# About SQL Server backup

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hey friends I have one problem related to SQL Server 2008 R2.

I set up Visual Studio 2010 on my system and then SQL Server 2008 R2. And now I am trying to restore the database in my system but it generates the Return Error 3241 error. And I could not restore the database.

One of my friend told me that since you have install the VS 2010 first you are running the SQL Server 2005 Express although SQL Server 2008 R2 has been installed, this is the problem you could not restore the database.

But now How can I solve my problem? I will be very thankful for the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have **both** SQL Server Express and SQL Server 2008 R2 installed, at least one of them is a **named instance**; most likely this will be SQL Server 2005 Express, installed as `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`.

The error indicates you're trying to restore a newer version backup to an older database (a 2008 R2 backup to a 2005 or 2008 server) - so are you trying to restore your 2008 R2 database onto the `(local)\SQLExpress` instance??

That will **never work**! SQL Server doesn't support restoring a backup from a newer version on an older server.

You need to restore it to your **real** 2008 R2 server instance! Possibly this is called your `(local)` server - possibly it has an instance name - not sure, you need to check this for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try this first :

```
Restore verifyonly from disk='Path\backupfile.bak'
```